# multicolumn layout with section issue

Tags: multicol

#### Issue

When using a `multicolumn` environment on a page where there is a section title, the two columns end up being one after the other instead of side by side.

It also seem to be resolved if the width of the images are less or equal than 79% of the `linewidth` (cf. screenshot down below).

#### Question

How to prevent that behaviour?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{sec:section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \columnbreak
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{multicols}
\vspace{-1em}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

#### Demo

1. With section

[image: with section]

2. Without section

[image: without section]

3. With `.79\linewidth`

[image: with low width]

Comment: Adding \leavevmode either before of after the start of multicols fixes it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo kind of ... more precisely it masks an error in graphics (and a questionable feature which may also be called error in multicol)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems you have hit a bug in graphics (amazing really) and your example also exhibits a bug or at least a questionable feature in multicol.

As for the bug in graphics: `\includegraphics` if starting a paragraph as it is the case in your example executes `\leavevmode` (as it should) but does that inside a group (as it should not).

As a result the heading setting for `\clubpenalty` which should be reset on the second paragraph is not reset or rather it is but then immediately changed back. Therefore the penalty between the two lines of the multicol paragraph (each one holding a picture) is 10150, i.e., no break allowed.

Proof:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} 

\begin{document}
\section{Section}\label{sec:section}
\lipsum[1]

\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\showthe\clubpenalty
\lipsum[1]

\stop
```

results in:

```
<example-image-a.pdf, id=1, 321.2pt x 240.9pt> <use example-image-a.pdf>
> 10000.
l.9 \showthe\clubpenalty

?
```

If you add a second paragraph before the graphic then everything is fine (which is what the `\leavevmode` does that was suggested.

Okay, so why has `\columnbreak` not broken between the two lines?
The answer here is, the columnbreak doesn't show up between the two graphics it actually shows up after them, i.e., in a fairly useless position.

Why is that? It adds a special penalty (using `\vadjust`) and that means it is inserted after the current line, but since the source code says

```
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \columnbreak
```

we have a full line graphic followed by a space (which marks the end of the line), so the column break command ends up in the second line thus the `\vadjust` appears after the second line.

```
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  \columnbreak
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
```

doesn't work either because then there is no breakpoint whatsoever between the graphics and the vadjust will again end in the same place.

So you have to write

```
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
  \columnbreak{}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
```

to make it work. I think I have a warning in the multicol documentation that `\columnbreak`is a little weird if used inside a paragraph, but anyway, there is something that could perhaps be improved (one day).